# Removing Python characters from a list

Tags: python

If i had a list as an example:

```
a = ['Hello_1.txt', 'Hello_2.txt']
```

In Python is it possible to somehow remove the first 5 characters (`'Hello'`) 
  and the last 3 characters (`'txt'`) from each of the items in the list ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list-comprehension and string slicing:

```
[s[5:-3] for s in a]
```

which gives what you describe (not sure this is the neatest output though!)

```
['_1.', '_2.']
```